# Qual è il senso dell'espressione "a ruota con" in questo brano?

Tags: meaning

Nel romanzo *La Storia*, di Elsa Morante, ho letto:

> «Noi siamo», le dichiarò il personaggio con grande enfasi, «per la pace nella vittoria, al minor costo possibile! E oggi, che la guerra-lampo dell’Asse sta per toccare la mèta della pace, plaudiamo alla lungimiranza del Capo, che assicura alla nostra Patria i vantaggi del successo col massimo risparmio. In una sola tappa, e senza rimetterci nemmeno il consumo delle gomme, eccoci già in volata al finale, giusto **a ruota con la Maglia Gialla**!!»

È evidente che questo personaggio fa una similitudine con l'ambito  del ciclismo. Non riesco a capire, però, il senso dell'espressione "a ruota con la Maglia Gialla" nel passaggio. Nel [vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/ruota) ho trovato che, nello sport del ciclismo, "seguire a ruota" significa seguire un altro corridore a breve distanza. Ma qui si è "a ruota con la Maglia Gialla" e non con un altro corridore. Significa questo che, anche se si tratta di una locuzione proveniente dall'ambito del ciclismo, si sta usando in senso figurato?

Comment: La Maglia Gialla _è_ un altro corridore. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Penso faccia riferimento al significato simbolico della Maglia Gialla, ossia quella del vincitore, del leader.

*La maglia gialla, simbolo del primato al Tour de France dal 1919*[image]

(Wikipedia)

Quindi, come ha detto @DaG, il significato
di "a ruota con la Maglia Gialla" nel contesto da te citato è appunto "a breve distanza del vincitore".

Comment: Possiamo considerarla una metonimia?

Comment: @RiccardoDeContardi: Penso di sì.